# Atom script wont run command

Tags: python, windows-10, window, atom-editor, python-3.8

I can execute code in Command prompt using python. But recently I downloaded Atom and downloaded script but when I tried to run my code there it said: "**python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**" Please Help! Also, I used .py and .python to save the file but it doesn't work either way. I just wrote my first line of code yesterday. Print ('Hello World"). I have windows by the way.

Comment: atom is just the editor, you will still need to install *python* preferably greater than 3.0 version. See this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: @FishingCode I already have installed python, i have 3.8, that how i was able to code python in CMD & Python IDLE, but I cant run my code on Atom Script.